# Node.js doesn't establish connection to Elasticsearch from docker container

Tags: node.js, docker, elasticsearch

I'm trying to connect my Node.js application to Elasticsearch with docker containers but without success.
I've tried many of the answers provided here in StackOverflow but none of them worked out for me.

Elasticsearch container is up and running and I can access to it in the browser with `localhost:9200` but it doesn't connect through the container name `elasticsearch:9200`.

I made a check with `curl elasticsearch:9200` and prints `curl: (6) Could not resolve host: elasticsearch`. Also tried with `curl http://host.docker.internal:9200` and the same error.

I can open Elastic Dashboard at `localhost:5601/app/observability/overview` but is not showing metrics panel obiously because of the Connection Error.

I've also checked console.log(`${config.ELASTIC_SEARCH_URL}`) and prints `http://elasticsearch:9200` and also tried with `node: ${config.ELASTIC_SEARCH_URL} || http://localhost:9200` as a fallback but neither of them works.

I tried to add notification service to elastic network but it immediately fails and also removed elastic network and tried to use the Docker network that adds by default but still the same error so I don't know how to get around this.

`curl localhost:9200`

```
{
  "name": "3e9d7110bb8a",
  "cluster_name": "docker-cluster",
  "cluster_uuid": "sAZvoS3YRSiewKxFqC1RhA",
  "version": {
    "number": "8.11.4",
    "build_flavor": "default",
    "build_type": "docker",
    "build_hash": "da06c53fd49b7e676ccf8a32d6655c5155c16d81",
    "build_date": "2024-01-08T10:05:08.438562403Z",
    "build_snapshot": false,
    "lucene_version": "9.8.0",
    "minimum_wire_compatibility_version": "7.17.0",
    "minimum_index_compatibility_version": "7.0.0"
  },
  "tagline": "You Know, for Search"
}
```

Elasticsearch docker-compose.yaml file:

```
version: '3.9'

services:
  elasticsearch:
    container_name: elasticsearch
    image: docker.elastic.co/elasticsearch/elasticsearch:8.11.4
    restart: always
    environment:
      ES_JAVA_OPTS: -Xmx2g -Xms2g
      discovery.type: 'single-node'
      xpack.security.enabled: 'false'
    ports:
      - 9200:9200
      - 9300:9300
    ulimits:
      memlock:
        soft: -1
        hard: -1
      nofile:
        soft: 65536
        hard: 65536
    deploy:
      resources:
        limits:
          cpus: '2.0'
        reservations:
          cpus: '1.0'
    networks:
      - elastic
```

Node.js notification service:

```
version: '3.9'

services:
  notification:
    container_name: notification
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: Dockerfile.dev
    restart: always
    ports:
      - 4001:4001
    environment:
      - NODE_ENV=development
      - ELASTIC_SEARCH_URL=http://elasticsearch:9200
    depends_on:
      - elasticsearch
```

Root docker-compose.yaml

```
version: '3.9'

services:    
  elasticsearch:
    extends:
      service: elasticsearch
      file: infra/docker/docker-compose-elasticsearch.yaml

  kibana:
    extends:
      service: kibana
      file: infra/docker/docker-compose-kibana.yaml

  notification:
    extends:
      service: notification
      file: api/notification/docker-compose.yaml
    depends_on:
      - elasticsearch

networks:
  elastic:
    name: elastic
```

The client code:

```
import { Client } from '@elastic/elasticsearch';
import { ClusterHealthResponse } from '@elastic/elasticsearch/lib/api/types';
import { config } from '@notification/config';
import { Logger } from 'winston';

const logger: Logger = winstonLogger(
  `${config.ELASTIC_SEARCH_URL}`,
  'notificationElasticSearchServer',
  'debug',
);

const elasticSearchClient = new Client({
  node: `${config.ELASTIC_SEARCH_URL}`,
});

export const checkConnection = async (): Promise<void> => {
  let isConnected = false;

  while (!isConnected) {
    try {
      const health: ClusterHealthResponse =
        await elasticSearchClient.cluster.health({});

      logger.info(
        `NotificationService ElasticSearch health status - ${health.status}`,
      );
      isConnected = true;
    } catch (error) {
      logger.error('Connection to ElasticSearch failed. Retrying...');
      logger.log(
        'error',
        'NotificationService checkConnection() method:',
        error,
      );
    }
  }
};
```

When I run docker-compose up it throws:

```
notification     | ERROR (ConnectionError):
notification     |     message: "NotificationService checkConnection() method: Connect Timeout Error"
notification     |     meta: {
notification     |       "headers": {},
notification     |       "meta": {
notification     |         "aborted": false,
notification     |         "attempts": 3,
notification     |         "connection": {
notification     |           "_openRequests": 0,
notification     |           "deadCount": 0,
notification     |           "headers": {},
notification     |           "id": "http://elasticsearch:9200/",
notification     |           "pool": {
notification     |             "_events": {},
notification     |             "_eventsCount": 0
notification     |           },
notification     |           "resurrectTimeout": 0,
notification     |           "timeout": 30000,
notification     |           "tls": null,
notification     |           "url": "http://elasticsearch:9200/",
notification     |           "weight": 1000
notification     |         },
notification     |         "context": null,
notification     |         "name": "elasticsearch-js",
notification     |         "request": {
notification     |           "id": 1,
notification     |           "options": {},
notification     |           "params": {
notification     |             "headers": {
notification     |               "accept": "application/vnd.elasticsearch+json; compatible-with=8,text/plain",
notification     |               "user-agent": "elasticsearch-js/8.12.1 (linux 6.5.0-17-generic-x64; Node.js 21.6.2; Transport 8.4.0)",
notification     |               "x-elastic-client-meta": "es=8.12.1,js=21.6.2,t=8.4.0,hc=21.6.2"
notification     |             },
notification     |             "method": "GET",
notification     |             "path": "/_cluster/health",
notification     |             "querystring": ""
notification     |           }
notification     |         }
notification     |       },
notification     |       "statusCode": 0,
notification     |       "warnings": null
notification     |     }
notification     |     options: {
notification     |       "redaction": {
notification     |         "additionalKeys": [],
notification     |         "type": "replace"
notification     |       }
notification     |     }
notification     |     service: "notificationElasticSearchServer"
notification     |     stack: "ConnectionError: Connect Timeout Error\n    at SniffingTransport.request (/notification/node_modules/.pnpm/@elastic+transport@8.4.0/node_modules/@elastic/transport/lib/Transport.js:541:31)\n    at process.processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:95:5)\n    at async Cluster.health (/notification/node_modules/.pnpm/@elastic+elasticsearch@8.12.1/node_modules/@elastic/elasticsearch/lib/api/api/cluster.js:183:16)\n    at async checkConnection (/notification/src/elastic/index.ts:2:1393)"
```

Comment: What is `@notification/config`? I can't find it in the NPM registry

Comment: There are a lot of variables. I recommend to start to check if the elasticsearch is up and running `curl localhost:9200`.

Comment: @Phil @notification/config is a typescript path alias.

Comment: @Musab Dogan yes elasticsearch is up and running.

Comment: As a workaround, you can ssh into node.js docker and try to curl the elasticsearch from there. I suspect there is a network issue

Comment: Yes is a network issue but if I cannot attach node.js container to elastic network because fails, what else could I do ? I just don't understand why I can't with simple networking. SSH doesn't work neither.

I attached a shell and tried with > /notification $ ping localhost:9200
PING localhost:9200 (127.0.0.1): 56 data bytes